# Forward unencrypted imap traffic into TLS-enabled?

Tags: imap

Specifically in this example, I'm looking toward the ProtonMail Bridge, which will soon be available for Linux.

For those unaware, this sets up a local imap server that decrypts your mail and allows you to use third party mail clients. Because it's only meant to be used locally, it doesn't encrypt the IMAP traffic.

Is there any application I could use to connect to the bridge, then run a second IMAP server (which will be open to WAN) which can forward encrypted traffic?

Comment: If you *want* to do that, are you sure ProtonMail is the most suitable setup for your needs? Anyway, simplest solution to "how do i access insecure tcp protocol X remotely?" type of problems will always be to forward the port via ssh.